# Best way to sort a data structure of assorted objects by one sort variable?

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting

Given a list/array of objects containing some other objects, I'm looking to sort by using one of the parameters. For example, if I have a multi-dimensional array of ints and I want to sort by their midpoint.

The way I'm doing it is to create an anonymous object containing 1. the midpoint and 2. a list of the 2 ints for each entry. Then enlist these objects and use reflection to access and sort by the midpoint parameter.

Is there a more standard approach to this problem? It's a bit clumsy because I have to create a dummy and clear the anonymous list object in order to do it.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[,] input = new int[,] { { 5, 6 }, { 0, 1 }, { 2, 20 } };

        var itemList = new []{ 
          new { sortVar = 0.1f, item = new List<int>() } }.ToList();

        itemList.Clear();

        for(int i=0; i<input.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            List <int> temp = new List<int> (new int[] { input[i,0], input[i, 1] });

            var item = new { 
              sortVar = float.Parse((input[i,0]+input[i,1]).ToString())/2,
              item = temp };

            itemList.Add(item);
        }

        var itemList2 = itemList.OrderBy(x => x.sortVar);
    }
}
```

Comment: [Code-review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A short linq version of your approach would be to use the [Average](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358946(v=vs.110).aspx) method directly in the `OrderBy` clause (if you are inclined to use a 2-D List):

```
List<List<int>> input_List = new List<List<int>> 
{
    new List<int>{ 5, 6 }, 
    new List<int>{ 0, 1 }, 
    new List<int>{ 2, 20 } 
};

var output = input_List.OrderBy(x=>x.Average()).ToList();
```

**EDIT:**

If you need to order it by the median you can use this expression:

```
var output = input_List.OrderBy(x=>x.OrderBy(y=>y).ElementAt(x.Count / 2)).ToList();
```

Comment: *Mid point* is not `Average` but *Median* - middle item in the sorted array: `[1, 2, 100] -> 2; [1, 2, 4, 100] -> (2 + 4) / 2 == 3`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko looking at OP's code he is not calculating the median but the mean: `float.Parse((input[i,0]+input[i,1]).ToString())/2` when I try his code `sortVar` has values of `0.5`, `5.6` and `11`. which is definetely not the median

Comment: in case array has `1` or `2` items, median equals to average

Comment: @DmitryBychenko although the calculation seems still like mean to me :) I added a median version to my post. Thank you for emphasizing.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the solution. Could you explain a bit what's going on in `OrderBy(y=>y).ElementAt(x.Count / 2) `? I'm struggling to understand how this is able to produce the median.

Comment: @Totoro this statement orders the elements in the sublist and then takes the middle item. if the count of the sublist is 2 it will take the first, if count is 4 it will take the third: `4/2=2`. This statement does not calculate the avarage of the midpoint elements like Dmitry showed in his example or in the comment above: `[1, 2, 4, 100] -> (2 + 4) / 2 == 3`

Comment: Ahhh ok got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest changing *2D* array into *jagged* one (array of array):

```
   int[][] input = new int[][] { 
     new int[]{ 5,  6 }, 
     new int[]{ 0,  1 }, 
     new int[]{ 2, 20 } };
```

And extract the criterium (`MidPoint`) as a method

```
   private static double MidPoint(IEnumerable<int> value) {
      int[] sorted = value.OrderBy(item => item).ToArray(); 

      // / 2.0: we don't want integer division: (1 + 4) / 2 == 2 when (1 + 4) / 2.0 == 2.5
      return sorted.Length % 2 == 0
        ? (sorted[sorted.Length / 2 - 1] + sorted[sorted.Length / 2]) / 2.0
        : sorted[sorted.Length / 2];
    }
```

Tnen if you want to sort *in place* use `Array` class:

```
 // input will be sorted 
 Array.Sort(input, (a, b) => MidPoint(a).CompareTo(MidPoint(b)));
```

If you want to create a *new* sorted array:

```
 // we'll have to arrays: initial (unsorted) input, and sorted sortedInput
 var sortedInput = input
   .OrderBy(line => MidPoint(line))
   .ToArray();
```